# Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.ClassCastException:int[]

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error only android 7 and 7.1.1

```
Exceção fatal: android.app.RemoteServiceException
Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.ClassCastException: int[] 
cannot be cast to android.app.PendingInten

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1644)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6123)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(ZygoteInit.java:867)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I think that this occurs here:

```
startForeground(ID_NOTIFICATION,  mBuilderCompat.build());
```

Comment: What is your `ID_NOTIFICATION` value ?

Comment: ID_NOTIFICATION it is a int value

Comment: Is it equal to 0 ?

Comment: It is equal to 7870